# Iterate rows in polygon, use result to select by location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-location, iterator

I'm not overly familiar with iterators but basically I have a polygon with multiple rows. I want to select each row in that polygon feature class and use the selected polygon in a select by location process to highlight the number of points within the polygon.

LatestOutages is my polygon file with about 8 rows in it. April is my points file with about 100 points in it. 
I want to use the polygon in each row to find the points it contains and input the count of points in each polygon as an attribute to the original polygon file.

I need to do this every single day and could have 50+ rows in each polygon feature class so it's not feasible to do it manually. Can someone show me the set up in modelbuilder?

Comment: No need for iterators. Use Spatial Join to get a Point Count per polygon.